# How can I divide a body into five equal sections

Tags: html, css, layout

I've been away from HTML and CSS for a couple years. How can I divide a page's body into 5 equal sections horizontally that will change size as the page is resized. This feels like it should be easy, but I can't really get my mind around it.

Comment: use percentage widths (for for 5 sections you need `width: 20%`). If you meant you want rows, instead, you'd use `height:20%`.

Comment: please could you clarify if you need 5 rows  or 5 columns? answers are discordant

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan, When you divide something horizontally, that means 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Also i added borders so that you could see the division of the sections

HTML

```
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
<section>
</section>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
section{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#222;
    box-sizing:border-box; /* so the borders don't mess up the alignment */
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/noajkkhj/

Comment: I modified your code to fit my needs so I accept your answer though all of these answers are similar. The trick was the float:left. That is what I had forgotten. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/8pqwo5eb/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
section{
  height: 20%;/*body height is 100% so, 100%/5=20%*/
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you.. but I think you meant width. He said horizontally.

Comment: *equal sections horizontally*:  I think @BhojendraNepal is right. Anyway an example provided by OP would have been a better start point and probably the downvoter could either explain the downvote or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `<div>` element's width by percent. So setting the width to 20% would give you a fifth of the width of the entire page. (You may have to use less to accommodate padding and borders.)

To have it fit the browser window, those should be inside a `<body>` that is set to take up the entire window.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,html{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

section{
display:inline-block;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #d2d2d2;
border: solid 1px #ccc;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have each section `width:20%` `float:left` with the body `width: 100%`.